# Using decltype to return iterator

Tags: c++, c++14, decltype

I have this class:

```
template <typename T>
class Hybrid
{
public:
    Hybrid() : m_activeStackSize(0) {}

private:
    std::list<T> data;

    size_t m_activeStackSize;

    auto internal_peek() -> decltype(data)::iterator
    {
        if (m_activeStackSize) // peek from stack
        {
            decltype(data)::iterator itr = data.end();
            std::advance(itr, -1);
            return itr;
        }
        else //peek from queue
        {
            decltype(data)::iterator itr = data.begin();
            return itr;
        }
    }
};
```

When trying to compile this on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 I get :

> main.cpp(12): error C3646: 'iterator': unknown override specifier

I don't understand why it won't let me return an `iterator` of type `std::list<T>` while the body code :

```
decltype(data)::iterator itr = data.end();
```

And

```
decltype(data)::iterator itr = data.begin();
```

Compile successfully.

How would I successfully return an `std::list iterator` using `decltype` explicitly?

Removing `-> decltype(data)::iterator` does compile successfully.

**Edit:**
Compiling with GCC and adding `typename` for every `decltype` [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/3dj4Hl), MSVC still errors out.

Comment: And with `typename` ?

Comment: I feel like I'm forced to add this obligatory comment: are you doing this just for fun, to see how decltype works? Because in real code, you should just use auto in this situation, ``auto itr = data.end();``, then you can do ``decltype(itr)`` if you actually need the type for something later, which is rare (and doesn't apply to this code).

Comment: @NirFriendman This is indeed just for fun. I also could've just removed the explicit type return in the function header but this error doesn't make sense, reason I asked if it was just a bug or my code.

Comment: That damned MSVC... :)

Comment: [this](http://rextester.com/YJSZ14903) usage of `decltype` seems to compile in MSVC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`decltype(data)::iterator` is a dependent type. Hence, you must use `typename`.

```
auto internal_peek() -> typename decltype(data)::iterator
                       //  ^^^^^ here
{
    if (m_activeStackSize) // peek from stack
    {
        typename decltype(data)::iterator itr = data.end();
        // ^^^^^ and here
        std::advance(itr, -1);
        return itr;
    }
    else //peek from queue
    {
        typename decltype(data)::iterator itr = data.begin();
        // ^^^^^ and here
        return itr;
    }
}
```

Possible work around for MSVC.

```
// Declare iterator as a type.
using iterator = typename std::list<T>::iterator;

iterator internal_peek()
{
    if (m_activeStackSize) // peek from stack
    {
        iterator itr = data.end();
        std::advance(itr, -1);
        return itr;
    }
    else //peek from queue
    {
        iterator itr = data.begin();
        return itr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited my question. GCC accepts it, MSVC still does not with the same eror message.

Comment: @JameyD, You are using gcc with C++14. The need for using `typename` may have evolved. You need it for C++11.

Comment: What I meant was that _with_ `typename` GCC accepts it, without it it doesn't ( C++14 ). Even _with_ `typename` however, MSVC still doesn't accept it.

Comment: @JameyD, MSVC seems to be behind. I hope you find a suitable work around.

Comment: @JameyD, what do you want from this poor thing? (MSVC)

Answer (score 2):

In C++14, you do not need decltype() at all. Following is correct per C++14 (as far as I know, MSVC does not fully support C++14):

```
   auto internal_peek()
    {
        if (m_activeStackSize) // peek from stack
        {
            auto itr = data.end();
            std::advance(itr, -1);
            return itr;
        }
        else //peek from queue
        {
            auto itr = data.begin();
            return itr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mhm, that does compile as I said in the question. I was just wondering if there was a way to do this with explicit typing.

Comment: @JameyD, oh, I didn't see it. May I ask you why do you want it?

Comment: As I said to Nir it isn't any "real" code. I was just testing out `decltype` and then I encountered this weird error. It seems to just be a bug in MSVC though. So I just want to abuse MSVC, really.